# Python error with flattening list of lists

Tags: python, list, flatten

Hi I'm trying to flatten the following list of lists but I always get the following error:

'int' object is not iterable

I also tried chain from itertools but still not working. I guess the solution is easy but I really cannot see it! Anybody can help?

Thanks

```
 from itertools import chain

import operator

lista = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]

listone = lista[0][0],[-x[0] for x in lista[:2]]

#sumlistone = chain.from_iterable(listone)

sumlistone = [x for sublist in listone for x in sublist]

print listone

print sumlistone
```

Comment: Print the contents of `listone`. Is it what you expected?

Comment: You probably want `listone = [lista[0][0]]  + [-x[0] for x in lista[:2]]`, but then `listone` already _is_ a flat list. Or did you want to create `sumlistone` from `lista` instead? What is the purpose of `listone`?

Comment: Listone is just an intermediate list, your solution just works fine for me!! Thanks

Comment: and yes the print of listone was already what I espected.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
lista = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
listb = []

for sub in lista:
    listb.extend(sub)    # Modification suggested by @Dinesh Pundkar 

print(listb)
print(sum(listb))
```

Comment: extend will save one line

Comment: listb.extend(sub)